# Android MLKit ocr: Waiting for the text optional module to be downloaded

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-mlkit

Android mlkit ocr not working on some devices. (Galaxy Tab Active3 SM-T577)

Firebase Crashlytics log;

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Waiting for the text optional module to be downloaded. Please wait.
   at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzb.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@17.0.0:16)
   at com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@17.0.0:1)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.4.0:4)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(:10)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzp.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.4.0:2)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.4.0:4)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.4.0:1)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(:2)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.4.0:2)
   at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(:2)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Gradle;

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:language-id:17.0.4'
```

Mafinest;

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
android:value="ocr" />
```

I tried;

- I uninstalled and reinstalled the app.
- Google Play Store clear all data.

Comment: Mustafa have you found a solution? Thanks

Comment: If you're going to use MLKit OCR, I haven't found any solution other than @Vinh's for now. So I replaced it with Tesseract OCR. You can see the sample project here.
Link: https://github.com/SubhamTyagi/android-ocr

Answer (score 3):

Solved the same problem using

```
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.0'
```

Comment: You are super man!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

1. Rebooting the device
2. Clearing data for Google Play Services (Settings - Apps - Google Play Services - Clear data)
3. Having more than one gig of storage available